# jquery .animate() - changes occur suddenly after the animation time, with no visible transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to animate the position of a div that has `position:relative`, like so:

```
$("#target").animate({
    top: '200px',
    left: '200px'
  }, 1000)
```

What happens is that after the time period, the attributes suddenly change to those in the .animate params.  There's no apparent transition: the div sits there for a second then instantly moves to the new position.

I've tested this in a js fiddle with the same version of jquery, and it works fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/j35o8re3/

Has anyone encountered this problem?  I've been googling a bit and haven't found anything useful so far.  thanks, Max

Comment: The posted fiddle seems to work perfectly fine for me ?

Comment: @adeneo that is what Max said. Max, I'm guessing you must have something else interfering with the animation in some way since it works fine in the fiddle, but not in your environment.

Comment: could it be something as simple as it executing before the documents finished loading? what about wrapping it in `$(document).ready(function() {`?

Comment: @Zack yes, that was my guess, but I don't know where to start trying to work out what.  I was hoping someone would come along and say "Yes, I had that and it was because ...."

Comment: I think you just need to start ripping pieces out until you find the one thing that is causing your issue.

Comment: @Hazonko I'm trying it in the chrome dev tools console.  It is doing "something", it's just missing the smooth transition.

Comment: @Zack I'll try saving it out as a static file and then ripping bits out like you say.  I have done this before, and it has worked, but it's a really slow process.

Comment: Generally, when the animation doesn't work, and the element just moves, you're either trying to animate table elements, or you haven't set a proper initial value for jQuery to start from.

Comment: @adeneo would you mind expanding on your last point?  (it's not a table element but i'm not sure what you mean by a proper initial value)

Comment: The element has to have position, and you should set an initial value, for instance `left : 0px` otherwise the CSS `left` property could be things like `auto` etc. which jQuery doesn't understand, it can't animate from `auto` to `200px`

Comment: @adeneo I believe it does, but just to make sure i tried this:  `$("#target").css("left", "100px")` (which moved it) then did `$("#target").animate({"left":"200px"},1000);` Same deal, ie waits a second then moves it with no transitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after saving it as a static and ripping stuff out, I tracked the problem down to this style rule:

```
  transition: all 0.9ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
```

There's two things going on here:  the first is that the designer meant to enter "0.9s" but wrote "ms" instead, so it's doing it in 0.9 milliseconds instead of 0.9 seconds.

The second problem seems to be that the css-set transition duration and the duration I'm passing to my .animate() call seem to be fighting each other:  what seems to happen is that it **waits for the duration i passed through to `.animate()` and then animates it smoothly using the time specified in the css**.

As it happens, the time specified in the css (after i fixed it), of 0.9 seconds, is fine for me as an animation time, so I'm not passing a duration through to the `.animate` call.

In hindsight, I could have diagnosed this a lot faster by looking at the computed styles for the div, which includes this line:

```
  transition-duration: 0.9ms;
```

Thanks to everyone who read and commented, i'll upvote all comments.